# Using node-inspector with Grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js, node-inspector, gruntjs

Does someone used [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) with [Grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt) for application debugging? If not, Can you recommend a debugging tool for Grunt based apps?

I'm working with [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) for a server side app and I have [Grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt) to use separated tasks (this is because users can execute tasks separately).

Comment: console.log is your friend..  I would love to access node-inspector, but i think the debug tools are not part of V8.  As i understand it, the debug tools are a web app in their own right.  Correct me if im wrong here because I would like to do what your attempting.

Comment: Yes, logging system (I mean console.log or other kind of logging mechanism) will be always our friend, but what I am needing, is a different and more debuggable way.

By now, I found some missing requirements to my project with grunt so I've removed by now and I am using nodejs as it own so I can debug using node-inspector now. I know, it is not the solution, but it works.

I think, in a future, I will add grunt again with node-inspector and other tools/features added.

Last but not least, grunt it's awesome! I'm using it in other projects and really rocks!

Comment: Just started playing around with Grunt, also interested in that question...

Comment: @iancrowther, the tools web inspector uses are in V8. There is a project called `node-inspector` that talks to `node --debug`, providing the debug info to a browser that connects. This is awesome, because you can then connect Chrome to the node-inspector process, and use all the web inspector tools to debug your app.  https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector

Answer (score 135, accepted):

To run grunt in debug, you need to pass the grunt script to node explicitly:

```
node-debug $(which grunt) task
```

and put a `debugger;` line in your task. `node-inspector` will then open a browser with debugging tools.

#### Edit 28 Feb 2014

`node-inspector` has added the command `node-debug`, which launches node in a `--debug` state and opens the browser to the `node-inspector` page, stopping when it hits the first `debugger` line or set breakpoint.

#### Edit 30 January 2015

On Windows, things are a touch more complicated. See the answer from @e.gluhotorenko for instructions.

Comment: This is great.  It also works on other globally installed npm bins.

Comment: node debug $(which grunt) task uses nodejs default debugger

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with this. Could you clarify what `$(which grunt)` is? Is it just the Gruntfile.js I want to debug? And for `task` do I put (using `serve` as an example) `grunt serve` or just `serve`? I have tried `node-debug Gruntfile.js serve` and a lot of other things but I just cannot get this to work. Node-inspector opens and it breaks on the first line, but I cannot break into the `serve` task even if I put a `debugger;` line as the first line of the function.

Comment: @brett, are you on windows or OSX/Linux? On unix, $(which grunt) gets replaced with the full path to the grunt-cli `grunt.js` script. That is the script that actually runs Grunt. If you're on windows, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13443026/240358 (the answer below this) for a possible location of the grunt-cli script. That takes the place of `grunt` in your command - in your example, replace `task` with `serve`

Comment: Thanks @DavidSouther, do you want to add the windows-specific part to your answer? I really should just make the move to linux...

Answer (score 39):

#### Windows solution

Run

```
node --debug-brk c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt taskname
```

from cmd in the directory with your `Gruntfile.js`. Do not forget to put `debugger;` line in necessary places.

Comment: Starting with grunt 0.4 the grunt entry point is part of the `grunt-cli` package: `node --debug-brk [..]\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt`

Comment: Thank you so much for the Windows instructions. In powershell you can use the tilde to make this a bit less fragile `node --debug-brk (Resolve-Path ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt) taskname`

Comment: Man, I just spent 30 minutes figuring this out then updating my answer! I should have just scrolled down!

Comment: Do not forget to open another console and run `node-inspector`

Comment: @valter.santos.matos actually it is now you should use the node --inspect mentioned below

Answer (score 7):

To debug, we have to modify the grunt file under bin. On my machine, grunt is installed globally, so I went to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin
I opened the file and modified:

`#!/usr/bin/env node`

To

`#!/usr/bin/env node --debug-brk`

--debug-brk will break on the first line of javascript ran.

Doing that alone isn't quite enough though, since you won't be able to find you're grunt task js file in the drop down in node inspector, so you have to modify the file you're interested in debugging by adding `debugger;` where you want the breakpoint to happen. 
Now you can click continue after the first break, and you'll break on you're `debugger;` line

Pretty kludgy, but it's the only way I've found so far.

Comment: This is incredibly kludgy, since it relies on a variety of behavior in /usr/bin/env and undocumented magic between # and \n in the shebang line.

Comment: It does not work for me. Grunt still runs without debug mode.

Comment: @DavidSouther Shebangs aren't undocumented magic. They're standardised POSIX behaviour

Answer (score 6):

I recently created grunt-node-inspector to easily configure node-inspector with the rest of your grunt workflow, check it out: https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-node-inspector

Here is a section of a Gruntfile which illustrates how you can debug a grunt task using grunt-node-inspector, grunt-concurrent, and grunt-shell: https://github.com/CabinJS/Cabin/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L44-L77

Comment: You're thinking, run `node --debug-brk $(which grunt) node-inspector build test` sort of thing? I like that.

Comment: Pretty much, except I use concurrent, because `node-inspector` won't exit and allow `build` and `test` to run since it runs forever. I added a link to a snippet where I have it setup.

Comment: Hmm. On second thought... my workflow has me just starting `node-inspector &`, leaving it in the background, and calling it done. Any thoughts of yours about that?

Comment: Not sure why, but this doesn't seem to work for me. I run the command `grunt node-inspector` and then go to the localhost url and I see no source files. Just empty debugger tools.

Comment: I managed to get the source to show up by running two separate commands. `grunt node-inspector` and `node --debug-brk Gruntfile.js` from my grunt directory. However when I set a breakpoint in the grunt file it just crashes with a connection error.

Answer (score 4):

I have done a task to run my app and launch node-inspector.
It is far better than current proposition, you just have to add this task in gruntfile:

```
  grunt.registerTask('debug', 'My debug task.', function() {
        var done = this.async();
        grunt.util.spawn({
            cmd: 'node',
            args: ['--debug', 'app.js'],
            opts: {
                //cwd: current workin directory
            }
        },
        function (error, result, code) {
            if (error) {
                grunt.log.write (result);
                grunt.fail.fatal(error);
            }
            done();
        });
        grunt.log.writeln ('node started');
        grunt.util.spawn({
            cmd: 'node-inspector',
            args: ['&'],
            opts: {
                //cwd: current workin directory
            }
        },
        function (error, result, code) {
            if (error) {
                grunt.log.write (result);
                grunt.fail.fatal(error);
            }
            done();
        });
        grunt.log.writeln ('inspector started');
    });
```

Comment: The author of grunt-node-inspector has it right. This solution only works on posix environments while his is easier to configure node-inspector and with concurrent, works on posix and windows.

Answer (score 3):

Great answers here. **In 2017, now you can do**

`node --inspect --debug-brk $(which grunt) taskName`

Which prints something like.

`To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/232652c3-f63c-4b00-8de9-17dfad5db471`

Open that URL in chrome, and you're good to go!

I'm using Node 7.3.0 and I'm on Mac. You might have to follow some of the advice in other posts to get it going on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

**2019 update**

- If you want to launch the grunt task in debug mode and break at first line:

  `node --inspect-brk $(which grunt) taskName`
- If you want to launch the grunt task in debug mode at a specific port:

  `node --inspect-brk=8080 $(which grunt) taskName`
- if you want to attache VSCODE to the node process running the debugging session of grunt, use the following configuration in vscode:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach by port IP 5656",
      "port": 8080
    }
  ]
}
```