# How to write unit test for a grunt task

Tags: unit-testing, gruntjs

I wanna write unit test for my grunt task

```
var buster = require('buster');
buster.spec.expose();

var shell = require('shelljs');

var grunt = require('grunt');
var release = require('../tasks/grunt-mytask');

release(grunt)

buster.testCase("mytask", {
  "test": function () {
    this.stub(shell, 'exec');
    grunt.task.run('mytask');
    expect(shell.exec).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
});
```

Unfortunately the task seems never to be called in the test.

Comment: I have the same problem... finally did you fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using node-inspector with Grunt tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171013/using-node-inspector-with-grunt-tasks)