# How to Debug Grunt Mocha Task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, webstorm

I am using WebStorm to run a grunt task. The debugger successfully stops at the breakpoint in the Gruntfile.js file, but not in my task file.

In the Gruntfile.js I register a task like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ... configuration ...
});    
grunt.registerTask('myTask', ['mocha:myTask']);
```

When I set a breakpoint in the corresponding js file for the test 'myTask' it doesn't stop. 
How can I debug also the grunt tests?

---

### --- **UPDATE** ---------------------------------------

so i tried all of your possible solutions, but it does not solve my problem!

I am able to debug the grunt script itself, this is where the debugger actually stops (either in WebStorm or node-inspector). Also a breakpoint in Gruntfile.js is working.

The problem is, that I am not able to debug the actual Grunt task itself, registered with grunt like this:
    grunt.registerTask('myTask', ['mocha:myTask']);

I am also able to debug the mocha test itself. But I want to debug a mocha test called from grunt task runner. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you loading the task?

Comment: Maybe you can use this to help find where things are stopping:     grunt.registerTask('debug', function(arg){
        grunt.log.writeln(arg);
    }); Call the debug task and pass it a string. That string will be outputted to the console.

Comment: @MattBrennan I have updated my question... Do you mean that?

Comment: @MBielski yes, i can debug that, no problem. but how can i actually debug the 'loopmocha:myTask'?

Comment: Have you tried using a `debugger;` statement in your task file?   I've found that often fixes issues like this in webstorm.

Comment: @dc5 can you please give an example? Not sure how this is done ...

Comment: In your task file, place the debugger statement where you would like the debugger to break: `debugger;`

Comment: Have you considered using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)? Debugging your own javascript with a stack trace is a lot easier than some arbitrary configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I am able to debug my mocha tasks! Thanks for all your answers and comments, but unfortunately I have to select my own answer, because that is the only one that worked for me.

Thanks to this video I found out what I was missing: http://vimeo.com/97561531

Basically it was two things:

1. Add a "debug-brk" option to grunt's mocha configuration:

   ```
   grunt.initConfig({
       ...
           "options": {
               "mocha": {
                   ...
                   "debug-brk": (grunt.option('debug-brk')) ? "" : 0
               }
           }
   }
   ```
2. Configure WebStorm's Debug Configuration like this:

   [image: WebStorm's Debug Config to Halt on debug-brk]

Comment: How awesome that you found my video in solving your problem. Awesomer still, I was having an issue with debugging in web storm and newer versions of mocha. In googling for this issue I came across YOUR answer. Your small modification to the code I'd written earlier answered MY question… CHEERS!!!!

Answer (score 6):

To run grunt task in debug, you need to pass the grunt task script to node-inspector:

```
node-debug $(Path \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt) task
```

Put a `debugger;` line in your task. `node-inspector` will then open a browser with debugging tools.

This link help you how its work **[grunt-node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-node-inspector)**

Example: [ChrisWren/grunt-node-inspector](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-node-inspector)

Source: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171013/using-node-inspector-with-grunt-tasks)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work. I placed "debugger;" on the first line of the task.js file, but its not even visible anymore in the node-inspector and it is also not stopping.

Comment: @BenMarten Just take a look **[debugging-with-node-inspector](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/14/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-debugging-with-node-inspector/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use the **WebStorm IDE** you can set up a task and then either run or debug it.

You can see the configuration for the command `grunt jasmine_node_no_coverage` in the screenshot. Please note that I installed grunt globally.

[image: Configuration of the task in WebStorm]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to debug the code of grunt-mocha? If yes, then you need to set a break point in these sources. You should be able to find a line like `grunt.registerTask("mocha", function () { ... });`. The function is executed when you run a mocha task.

Comment: I only have a project that uses grunt with grunt-jasmine-node-coverage. And there it was stopping inside the function when I tried it out earlier today. I set the breakpoint in `./node_modules/grunt-jasmine-node-coverage/tasks/jasmine-node-task.js` on the first line of the function passed to registerTask: `grunt.registerTask("jasmine_node", "Runs jasmine-node.", function () { /* HERE */ var jasmine = require('jasmine-node'); /* ... */ });`

Comment: Yes sorry it is actually stopping. When I replace ['mocha:myTask'] with a real function and place the debugger within the function, it works, but not in mocha myTask.js file ...

Answer (score 0):

Try out [`grunt-debug-task`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-debug-task).

Its similar to node debugger. Just run the `grunt debug taskname`

I tried it out. It breaks sometimes but seems to work.