# How to use the Node debug module with Grunt?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

How can I use Node's [debug module](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) with Grunt?

I know that to use the module I need to set the `DEBUG` env var in the command line like so:

`$ DEBUG=* node app.js`

But, I am struggling to figure out how to do it with Grunt.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171013/using-node-inspector-with-grunt-tasks

Comment: I don't want to run node in debug mode. I want to use the third party debug module. I just don't know how to set the DEBUG variable running Grunt instead of setting it in the command line.

Comment: So you want to use [debug-module](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) in your grunt code?

Comment: You mean `var debug = require('debug')` and `set DEBUG=*` on command line...

Answer (score 1):

I used `grunt-env` to help set env variable in grunt as below:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

  // Env-specific configuration
  env: {
    options: {
      //Shared Options Hash
    },
    dev: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
      DEBUG: 'wukong:*,loopback:security:role,-not_this'
    },
    test: {
      NODE_ENV: 'test',
      DEBUG: 'wukong:*,-not_this'
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

However, it doesn't work because debug module load and save `process.env.DEBUG` at the very beginning of module initialization: https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/node.js#L209

Thus, I played a trick to load the `DEBUG` variable again via its "hidden" public API - [enable](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/debug.js#L171) as:

```
const debug = require('debug');
debug.enable(process.env.DEBUG);
module.exports = debug;
```

When this `debug` wrapper is used instead, `grunt` could print out debug message as expected.

Hope this workaround works for you as well. ;)