# How to debug my bower pluggable resolver?

Tags: node.js, bower

I can debug normal node applications by `node-inspector` and `node-debug` command.

How to debug my bower resolver?

I have only one idea: write another node app and require my bower resolver in it and use methods programmaticaly. Actually, I think that the correct way is to debug it on `bower install`.

So, how?

Comment: This seems way, way too broad.

Comment: What exactly is too broad there? I have custom bower resolver. It is node application. Actually, I can't run it just by `node .` and debug it like simple node application. That is the question: how to debug it if I can't do it like with any other simple bode application?

Comment: Because you're asking "How can I debug [class of program]."

Comment: Yes. If I will write `how to debug my programm on C#` it will be broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to write a well-tested answer, but you can try your luck with the following methods:

- use `console.log`, `console.dir` in resolver's code (you should see output when doing `bower install` although it depends how exactly the resolvers are invoked by bower)
- write a unit test (see [example](https://github.com/mjeanroy/bower-npm-resolver/blob/master/test/resolver-spec.js)) and debug it in isolation
- use a command like [`node-debug $(which bower) install`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739260/245966) (or `node --debug-brk /path/to/node_modules/bower/bin/bower` + `node_inspector` in separate console tab) to do integrated debugging; remember to put `debugger` statement in your JS file in the resolver's methods to pause in `node-inspector` at proper stage of execution

Comment: console.log is not the way to debug the code. Yes people can use it but it is not really well way :) I have unit tests and I can debug my code through it, this is not the way too. And yes I tried to debug my code with node-debug. It deesn't work =/

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? you have blank Chrome DevTools screen?

Comment: I am not right. Shame on me but I forgot about the `debugger` keyword. Main problem was (thats why I said it doesn't work) I couldn't find my resolver source files so I couldn't put breakpoint. Now I put debugger in the code and node-debug stopped on it. Works like a charm.

Comment: Cool :) basically with every globally installed node program like `grunt`, `gulp` etc you'd do the same, you need to find the main entry point with `which grunt` etc. and start `node-debug` with it as a parameter.